# root-android.org - A scam?

Tags: rooting, malware

I would just like to know whether the website [root-android.org](http://root-android.org/) and its product is a big scam when it comes to rooting Android devices. If it is, then I advice other would-be rooters to stay away from it if they were to come across it.

Comment: 30 bucks to root your Android? We would be rich if we would charge only half of the amount. Instead we give away this information for free @ Android Enthusiasts.

Comment: @Flow Very good point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this ScamWarners post](http://www.scamwarners.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=62280), it may be a SCAM.

> The site Root Android.org supposedly carries out the service of rooting and unrooting mobile phones with a "special" program. Like all scam sites "100% money back guarantee if not satisfied" is a in your face feature, alas nothing is further from the truth.
>   After initial email contact regarding technical issues with the downloaded program, there is nothing and certainly no contact when exercising the refund option.
>   I have since searched and found that the program Root Android.org uses is a free download from a few specific sites that deal openly with the global community.
>   The old warning of buyer be ware rings true, I sincerely would not use this site again and warn anybody who is contemplating mobile phone rooting to steer clear of Root Android.org.

Comment: For sure one program can't possibly be used for multiple devices, rooting depends on your specific phone & the version of Android running. My main point was to warn potential newcomers to Android, if they unsuspectedly came across the site and thought it was good idea.

Comment: What would prevent one program to be used for multiple devices? E.g. SuperOneClick comes with many rooting methods.

Comment: @Flow I thought that in order to Root, the method was specific to your individual phone, thanks for advising otherwise

Comment: @Simon each rooting exploit is specific to a "kernel bug", and such bound to (a range of) Android version(s). In some cases, manufacturers *might* backport fixes, so the exploit cannot be used on that device -- but in general, the exploit is not device-specific but Android-version-specific.

Comment: @Izzy Thx for clarification

Answer (score 3):

They are absolutely scammers. Their software, whatever it is, didn't work for me. Support "helped" by telling me to install a number of free software apps from the web and then never responded to further emails. SafeCart did not respond to email requests for a refund. After a week of trying to get someone to answer an email I finally called SafeCart and they issued a refund no questions asked.

Comment: Nothing better than an account from first hand experience

Answer (score 1):

They list testimonials, which are from anonymous people who may not exist, so like most testimonials those are worthless. They don't list any reviews from any publications or other sources you might trust. They talk about being mentioned on Google and other places, but those are just search engines that have found their site.

So they've got no credentials.

Maybe it works, maybe it bricks your phone, you MUST be prepared for that because everyone who roots is screwing around with things that sometimes brick phones, sometimes work, and none of the free advice is written clearly or works for long, as files keep getting taken down or obsoleted.

Use a credit card, if it bricks the phone charge it back if you don't get a prompt refund. if it really worked so well, how come they can't get anyone to review it and post the review? Not even forum threads from "known" forum members?

"If it sounds too good to be true" it must be a rooting solution. The guys who say rooting is easy and reliable, somehow never are capable of writing really clear and complete instructions on how to do it. Never.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely they gather rooting software or rooted kernels from XDA-Developers and sell them along with a guide also copied from there.

There isn't any fast way other than those you can find through a Google Search.

While I can't say it's a scam, I don't recommend you paying $30 for that. Better search Google for how to root your device and also add your Android version, because most of the time that matters.