# Is it safe visiting Droidmodapk.com?

Tags: applications, apk

Should I visit [Droid Mod Apk](http://Droidmodapk.com) site for Android Apps?

Comment: It hosts modded apps. No wonder it is unsafe for consumption. // Am I alone here suspecting this post as a potential spam to us?

Comment: OP: It's just a matter of trust.. You download apps from Play Store & use it because you trust Google. As far as I can see, since the apps over the site are modded ones, you can't be sure if it's safe. But I think you may use the apps, since it's a famous reputed site & you may use it for day-to-day purpose from my point of view.. (The site just hosts modded apk's, they are not modders I guess) // @Firelord I think the OP's question is genuine, he has no intention of spamming, eventhough the question seems to be off-topic for me.. How to deal with these kinda questions btw??

Comment: To close-voters: we do have [several](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63519/12442) [previous](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/135711/12442) [questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/39531/12442) in the same form, of which some have been closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the original site is dead and now it redirected to a questionable Chinese site.

Answer (score 4):

No. App piracy sites like this one are unsafe to download apps or games from. Usually the apps you're downloading have malware added to them, and sometimes they have only the malware and don't even contain the app they claim to.

We get so many questions on this site from people who install malware onto their own phones and then can't remove it: sometimes even a factory reset, deleting all the user data, is not enough.

Online security is mainly about thinking about motivation and trustworthiness. If this site really had access to all these paid apps and games, why would they run a high-traffic website - effectively paying for you to download them? If they didn't expect to get a big reward - by turning your phone into a botnet or stealing your data - why would they bother putting in all the SEO keywords? (SEO keywords are those repeated phrases you see on the site, like "APK OBB for Android download" on every link. Repeating the same phrase on every link isn't something an honest website does, because it makes the design worse, but dishonest websites do it to improve their Google rank.) Not having any contact information - or any clue about who operates the website - listed on the site is another red flag. Even [the whois data](https://who.is/whois/droidmodapk.com) - the official internet record of who owns and operates the site - is hidden behind a company in Panama.

Consider all those factors and then decide if you want to install software that you got from these people.